# Including Columns Inside Bootstrap Modal Tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to add a set of columns inside my Bootstrap modal. The following works fine (without columns):

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="updateModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-type="strength">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                  <h3 id="myModalLabel" class="text-center">Invoice <span class="itemID"></span></h3>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="tabbable">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="display: none">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                                <h3>Test</h3>
                                <h3>Test</h3>
                                <h3>Test</h3>
                                <h3>Test</h3>
                                <h3>Test</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                                <p>Data 2.</p>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
           </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

However, adding columns to the first tab throws off the formatting so that the bottom modal does not stretch to cover the contents.

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <h3>Test</h3>
        <h3>Test</h3>
        <h3>Test</h3>
        <h3>Test</h3>
        <h3>Test</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <h3>Test</h3>
        <h3>Test</h3>
        <h3>Test</h3>
        <h3>Test</h3>
        <h3>Test</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried to find the height determinant in the browser, but the property seems to be implicit. This seems like it should be simple enough, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remember that a `col-*` must always come directly under a `row`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the entire Bootstrap Grid Framework, not just `.col-*-*`.  So make sure you specify your `.container` (recommend `.container-fluid`) and your `.row`

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <h3>Test</h3>
                <h3>Test</h3>
                <h3>Test</h3>
                <h3>Test</h3>
                <h3>Test</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-5">
                <h3>Test</h3>
                <h3>Test</h3>
                <h3>Test</h3>
                <h3>Test</h3>
                <h3>Test</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This would mean nesting containers which is not supported. You don't need the container.

Comment: Adding just the row div works. For some reason it was breaking earlier, but seems to be working now. Thanks very much!

Comment: @DavidG - Very true, but given that the `.modal` shouldn't be wrapped in the `.container` in the first place...

Comment: Actually a modal can be anywhere it's just recommended to have it at the root so it doesn't pick up any ambient CSS styles.